# Google dfp ads with double id

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

i use google dfp to serve my ads in website. I need to serve in different place on desktop and in different place in mobile, so i try to make it like this:

```css
   .mobileShow { display: none;}

   /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */

   @media only screen

   and (min-device-width : 320px)

   and (max-device-width : 480px){ .mobileShow { display: inline;}}

   .mobileHide { display: inline;}

   /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */

   @media only screen

   and (min-device-width : 320px)

   and (max-device-width : 480px){  .mobileHide { display: none;}}
```

```html
<div class="mobileShow">
<div  id='div-gpt-ad-1421767832590-6' style='width:300px; height:250px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1421767832590-6'); });
</script>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mobileHide">
<div  id='div-gpt-ad-1421767832590-6' style='width:300px; height:250px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1421767832590-6'); });
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

and i add my code: .mobileshow in the place i want to show in mobile and in desktop .mobilehide.
but the dfp can serve only one code(id) in one page. the display:none; its not served but also the second code dont show. 
Can i have some help please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using you own CSS classes, I suggest you use DFP's builtin responsive ad support. You can define a size mapping so that your ads show up based on the viewport size.

See https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?hl=en